# Android Runnable class - cannot access property from run() method

Tags: android, runnable, stringbuffer

```
  class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
        public StringBuffer line2;
        public MyRunnable(StringBuffer _line){
             this.line2 = _line;
             Log.w("LINE", this.line2.toString());   // Return what it should
        }

        public void run(){
             console.append(this.line2.toString());   //Nothing happens here
        }
  }
```

This is my code. I have the problem that when accessing line2 from `run()` method it has 0 length.

**edit**: This is my call

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {             
            @Override
            public void run() {
                StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
                while(true){
                    char a = UART.serialRead(UART.fd);

                    if(a != 0){                         
                        if (a == '\r' || a == '\n'){
                            MyRunnable obj = new MyRunnable(line);
                            handler.post(obj);
                            line.delete(0, line.length());
                            obj = null;
                        }else
                            line.append(a); 
                    }                   

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

Any idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: whats wrong in 0 length? you just pass empty StrinBuffer in the ctor

Comment: Well it shouldn't be 0. Also I clearly see that the line that I pass is not empty.

Comment: have you calling thread on MyRunnable class ?

Comment: Yes I'm calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether you are instantiating MyRunnable class using the one argument constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post make
 MyRunnable obj = new MyRunnable(line.toString);
end get a string in MyRunnable. I'm not sure if line passed as copy or object but not a reference in your case. If it's reference than you line cleared before it used in MyRunnable.